# Apply a list of functions to an input

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'd like to apply a list of functions to an input.
For example, if my list fo functions is `[(+1),(*3),(+(-2))]` and my input is `5`, I would like to apply the functions from right to left, so the output would be `10`.

Comment: You can use `foldr` or `foldl` to reduct a list depends on the direction. To apply function user `$`.  In this case expression is: `foldr ($) 5 [(+1),(*3),(+(-2))]`

Comment: I don't think this is the same with the assigned duplicate since OP requires a composition of functions. I voted reopen. An answer could be `foldl1 (.) [(+1),(*3),(+(-2))] $ 5`

Comment: Agree with you, in the opposite direction we need different `f` because of `foldl` signature.

Comment: Use `Data.List.foldl1'`, though, to force evaluation of each function as it is processed.

Comment: @mkUltra Thank you for the help, I posted the solution as an answer so I could close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with mkUltras' comment:

> You can use foldr or foldl to reduct a list depends on the direction.
>   To apply function user $. In this case expression is: foldr ($) 5
>   [(+1),(*3),(+(-2))]

My final code: `succApply x n = foldr ($) n x`

Example inputs:

```
succApply [(+1),(*2),(+(-1))] 1 == 1
succApply [init, tail] [1..5] == [2,3,4]
succApply [(*2), id, (+1)] 5 == 12
```